# jsx-a11y returning Form label must have associated control when there is an htmlFor

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

I have this component:

```
// @flow
import React, { Element } from 'react';
import styles from './Label.scss';
import cs from 'classnames';

export const Label = ({
  id,
  htmlFor,
  invalid,
  required,
  children
}: {
  id: string,
  htmlFor: string,
  invalid: boolean,
  required: boolean,
  children: Element<*>
}) =>
  <label
    htmlFor={htmlFor}
    id={id}
    required={required}
    className={cs(
      styles.label,
      required ? styles.required : '',
      invalid ? styles.invalid : ''
    )}
  >
    {children}
  </label>;

Label.displayName = 'Label';
```

When I run eslint I get this error message even though there is an `htmlFor`:

> error: Form label must have associated control
>   (jsx-a11y/label-has-for) at
>   packages/ds-component-library/src/components/atoms/Label/Label.js:19:3:

Answer (score 13):

In your .eslintrc, try the following:

```
"rules": {
        "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": [ 2, {
            "components": [ "Label" ],
            "required": {
                "some": [ "nesting", "id" ]
            },
            "allowChildren": false,
        }]
    }
```

This is coming from: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/label-has-for.md

Good luck!

Comment: In my opinion disabling the eslint rules defeats the purpose of using eslint. 

The label associated with the input field has to have the htmlFor attribute. the htmlFor that you mentioned for the label should be the id of the input field. Wrap the input field inside the opening and the closing tags of the label.