# Pass eslint html-has-for with htmlFor in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have a stateless React component that looks like this:

```
const propTypes = exact({
  fieldId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
});

function Label({ fieldId, text }) {
  return (
    <label htmlFor={fieldId}>{text}</label>
  );
}

Label.propTypes = propTypes;
```

I am using eslint extended with the airbnb config. My eslint looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb"
}
```

My React code throws this error:

```
error  Form label must have associated control  jsx-a11y/label-has-for
```

I have clearly set an `htmlFor` attribute with a valid unique id string (which matches the id on an input elsewhere). Surely this is enough to pass this rule?

Comment: Are you sure that `fieldId` is not undefined?

Comment: @Timo The value is a defined string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsx-a11y returning Form label must have associated control when there is an htmlFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951806/jsx-a11y-returning-form-label-must-have-associated-control-when-there-is-an-html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to setting an `htmlFor` attribute and an `id` the input element has to be nested inside the label. 
You can, however, turn off the nesting requirement if you want. Something like this:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": [ 2, {
      "required": {
          "every": [ "id" ]
      }
  }]
  }
}
```

Issue related to your problem: 
https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/314

Docs: 
https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/label-has-for.md

Comment: if input has `name` attribute, it can be used for label `htmlFor` attribute and lint will pass

Answer (score 3):

It  seems like you've used it separately from your `<input/>` tag. According to [source docs](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/label-has-for.md#succeed) you should put the `<input/>` inside the `<label/>`. Or you can set your .eslintrc like this

```
"rules": {
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": 0
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Eslint doesn't know about the input element that's being rendered elsewhere in your code.  The error you're getting isn't complaining about the `htmlFor` attribute per se, it's complaining that as far as it can tell, your `htmlFor` doesn't refer to a form control element (ie- your input).

Try rendering the input alongside your label in the same component, this error should go away.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I thought this might be the case so already tried what you suggest. Same error...